# what's the mean of /proc/self/fd/ socket file on linux system and how to found port

Tags: linux, sockets, networking

I am confused about the output below :

```
cd /proc/2045 ; ls -l fd
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 10月  8 19:04 66 -> socket:[294364529]
```

what does `socket:[294364529]` mean ?

I guess it should be a socket opened by this thread, but what does the number mean ?

How can I find the `port` or `Unix socket` path corresponding to this ?

thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your example "2045" is pid number of process and "294364529" is inode number of socket. In Linux sockets use normal file operations so this is why they have inode numbers.

Example:
Let assume that I have in system socket with inode number 4654214.

Netstat:

```
netstat -alep | egrep -i "Inode|4654214"
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:9999                  *:*                     LISTEN      root       4654214     10619/nc
```

Lsof:

```
lsof -i | grep "4654214"
nc        10619            root    3u  IPv4 4654214      0t0  TCP *:9999 (LISTEN)
```

More raw info (fot tcp):

```
 grep -i "4654214" /proc/net/tcp
   5: 00000000:270F 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 4654214 1 cc2c5f00 300 0 0 2 -1
```

This is way how you can get useful info about sockets. Additionally look at ss command.

Comment: Why are the sockets printed using red color font?